# MI Max 2 soft-bricked

Tags: diagnostics

Okay here is what happened Yesterday I restrated my phone beacuse the volume and power keys were acting funny but instead of booting into the system in boots into TWRP btw just in case I installed a custom rom before i restarted this okay back to the problem today I gave up trying to flash new custom roms since It keeps booting into TWRP so i decided to go with the stock rom I flashed with Miflash hoping it would fix but now TWRP is gone can't turn off my phone,can't boot into fastboot or bootloader,all I can is Mi-Recovery 3.0 also just to add my volume up key wont work that's the reason for why i think there is damage on my volume up key.

From the Main Menu of Mi-Recovery 3.0 all i could do is reboot to system which just makes it boot bact to recovery and wipe data which also did'nt work, Connect with MIAssistant is also useless since the app cant detect it. Thats all.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94776/discussion-on-question-by-need-help-mi-max-2-soft-bricked).

Answer (score 0):

Your phone boots into recovery because of a short circuit in the Volume Button.

- From TWRP Recovery, get a backup of boot partition and
- copy the `boot.emmc.win` file to PC via MTP-USB
- tap "Reboot" and "Bootloader" to enter fastboot mode
- boot your phone from fastboot with

  ```
  fastboot boot "C:\Users\<profil>\Desktop\boot.emmc.win"
  ```
- you must repeat the last step each time you want to boot into system